# The method 'toRawHandle' was called on null but I'm not using FirebaseMessaging

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I got an exception in `object_patch.dart`, located in `/Users/ME/development/flutter/bin/cache/dart-sdk/lib/_internal/vm/lib`

> The method 'toRawHandle' was called on null

I have followed the instructions [here](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/migration/) which was mentioned as a solution to related kind of problem from the [post here](https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire/issues/279#issuecomment-721832840).

Moreover, all the posts I found on this topic are related to FirebaseMessaging.
But I'm not using FirebaseMessaging.

Here is the Firebase dependencies in my `pubspec.yaml`:

```
  firebase_core: ^0.5.3
  firebase_auth: ^0.18.4
  cloud_firestore: ^0.14.4
  firebase_storage: ^5.2.0
  firebase_database: ^4.4.0
  cloud_functions: ^0.7.2
```

And my `main.dart`:

```
void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  
  runApp(MyApp());
}
```

Anyone knows what I might be missing?

Note: This only happens in Visual Studio Code (now version 1.51.1).
However, this problem does not happen in Android Studio (now version 4.1.1).

Comment: Since the error occurs on VS Code only I would say that there is some kind of broken dependency going on during your build, try doing a flutter clean and then building it again. Also, you could try, as a test, adding the `firebase_messaging` dependency even though you are not using just to check what happens. Let me know if this helps.